# A more technical definition of an Affine Variety

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

My textbook states that an affine variety is

> **Definition.** Let $k$ be a field and let $f_1,...,f_s$ be polynomials in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Then we set $$V(f_1,...,f_s)=\{(a_1,...,a_n) \in k^n : f_i(a_1,...,a_n)=0, \forall 1 \leq i \leq s\}$$
>
> We call $V(f_1,...,f_s)$ the *affine variety* defined by $f_1,...,f_s$.
>
> (*Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms* by Cox, Little and O'Shea)

My question is, simply, must an affine variety contain "ALL" the solutions to each $f_1,...,f_s$? So say, for simplicity I try to find a variety $V=V(f)$ for some $f$ then, can $V$ still be referred to as an "affine variety" while containing maybe only partial solutions?

I think the answer is no, and it MUST contain all solutions(otherwise, a particular variety will not be unique) but it's just that the definition above doesn't seem to (to me) make that very obvious. It seems like there's no problem letting it be the set with only "some" solutions too.

Can anyone point out which part of the definition makes this clear? Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "*all* solutions to each $f_1,\dots,f_s$"? The variety $V$ is defined as the *common* zeros of all the $f_i$, i.e. solution to the system of simultaneous equations $f_1=f_2=\cdots=f_s=0$.

Comment: So, say $f=x^2-y$. I trust the (affine) variety $V(f)=V(x^2-y)$ would contain, ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x^2-y=0$. By "ALL" solutions I meant the usual sense i.e. in this case, every ordered pair that allows $f(x,y)=$ say, in $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, I can have $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ as an example of a solution, but, my question was, can $V(f)=\{(0,0)\}$ or $V(f)=\{(1,1)\} \leftarrow$ (partial solution set) etc and not $\{(0,0),(1,1),(-1,1)\} \leftarrow$ (ALL solutions set)? I think "no" i.e. has to be the full solution set but I don't see that explicitly in the definition above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $V(f_1,\dots,f_s)$ contains all the solutions.  That is exactly what its definition means.  When you define a set $V$ by writing $V=\{x\in X:P(x)\}$, this means that $V$ is *the* set of *all* elements $x\in X$ such that $P(x)$ is true.  In this case, $X=k^n$, $x=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is written as an $n$-tuple, and $P(x)$ is the statement "$f_i(a_1,...,a_n)=0, \forall 1 \leq i \leq s$".

Comment: Thank you very much for a straightforward and clear answer, that got me back on track. I now see where in the definition that "all" solutions come to play. I appreciate it

Answer (score -2):

Usually $k$ is assumed to be algebraically closed, so that there is a correspondence between varieties and systems of equations (or rather the radical ideal defined by the polynomials).   For non-alg-closed fields or rings $K$ you talk about the $K$-points of the variety but the set of points is not considered to **be** (or to define) the variety.

For example, high degree polynomial equations $P(x,y)=0$ tend to have have an empty set of points over $K=\mathbb{Q}$, but they still can be thought of as curves and attributes of curves such as automorphisms, points at infinity, self-intersections, etc, can be useful in understanding the equation.  One does not think of the variety corresponding to the equation as "the empty set", but a field- or ring-dependent set of points that happens to be empty in some special cases.

Comment: This is true, but isn't at all what the question is asking, and in the context of the question is potentially misleading.

Comment: There wasn't a well-defined question.  I took part of the confusion to be whether (in more precise language) a variety is determined by a subset of its points.  I can't imagine what you consider potentially misleading.